# Using enter key to signin a user when using custom policy in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In the default signin policy, an *Enter keypress* triggers the actual signin action. However, when I create my own custom policy (using the `selfAsserted`-form as a basis, it doesn't work. With the custom policy, the user needs to either click the *Continue* button or use tab to move focus onto the button and then press *Enter*. Everything else works just as I'd like it to, but this seems like such an inconvenience.

Any idea why this might happen? Has someone else encountered this and found a solution?

This would be easy to fix manually, if it was
possible to include custom JavaScript code in the "template" HTML file that the *Azure AD B2C* injects the policy-complying form into. However, this doesn't seem to yet be possible either (as stated [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br) ).